# I to confirm with someone

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, headlinese

I really often see phrases when after pronoun or someone's name follow infinitive. Examples:

- Alex to confirm with Dan
- I to make a text
- Peter to develop a code

What does it mean? Is there should be some verb before infinitive? Does some rule exist?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

It's a kind of shorthand for things like "Alex *is* to confirm with Dan" or "Alex *is going* to confirm with Dan, meaning "It is planned that Alex will confirm with Dan."  We often use *to be* + **to** + *verb* to refer to plans, future events, instructions, etc. and sometimes when writing out headlines, lists, or instructions we leave out common words, ones that would be repeated often, or ones that can be understood from context.

Reference: [Advanced Grammar – “To be to”](https://blog.abaenglish.com/advanced-grammar-to-be-to/)

Answer (score 0):

These are not full sentences, and I would not expect to find them in prose. They are in the different grammar of notes, titles, headlines, where words are often omitted.